# Magento2 compliling specific theme deploy error --area does not exist

Tags: theme, magento-2.1, deploy

I wanted to deply chosen theme by using the guide from [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html) when I run `magento setup:static-content:deploy --area frontend --no-fonts --theme Magento/luma` the error is `--area does not exist` and I'm on Magento 2.1.0.

Comment: Command support only version of Mangeto 2.1.1

Comment: You can check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command `magento setup:static-content:deploy --area frontend --no-fonts --theme Magento/luma` only working with Magento 2.1.1

If you want to use of them then you have to upgrade mangeto vesrion.

If you are working with current version then use below command.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: I'm compiling specific theme only

Answer (score 1):

You shold use `=` after long parameters.
Run

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --area=frontend --no-fonts --theme Magento/luma
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deploy only specific theme for a store,

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --area=frontend 
>   --theme Magento/luma

In above command you can change Magento/luma with your custom theme, if your custom theme name like **Customtheme/themename**

run command like,

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --area=frontend 
>   --theme Customtheme/themename

**if you have language specific theme then you can do it like below,**

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --area=frontend --language
>   en_US --no-fonts --theme Magento/luma

where

**1. --area**

```
 Area are frontend and adminhtml are possible.
```

Ex.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --area=frontend
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --area=adminhtml
```

**2. --theme**

```
 Theme are Magento/luma, Magento/blank, Customtheme/themename
```

Just example,

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --area=frontend --theme=Magento/luma --theme=Magento/blank
```

**3. --language**

```
Language is your theme language,
just for , --language en_US --language fr_FR --language es_ES
```

ex.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --area=frontend --language en_US --language fr_FR
```

**4. --exclude**

```
You can exclude theme by using --exclude-theme Magento/luma
```

Ex. You can exclude specific theme by below command

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --area=frontend --exclude-theme Magento/luma
```

Comment: I'm compiling specific theme only

Comment: apparently you can : Generating static view files for one theme and one area

The following command generates static view files for all languages, the frontend area only, the Magento Luma theme only, without generating fonts:

Comment: You can specify language specific static content

Comment: if you have two different language at that time you want to deploy only one language at time then your command is like this,  php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy fr_FR

Comment: nope, i just want to deploy one theme here.

Comment: You can specify theme only setting based on append --area=frontend --no-fonts --theme Magento/luma